# jQuery: не получается вырезать и вставить элемент во второй раз

Tags: javascript, jquery

Дано: контейнер с тремя элементами. Задача: взять первый элемент и переместить его в конец контейнера (будет последовательность 2, 3, 1), затем сделать ещё раз то же самое для ставшего первым элемента (будет в результате 3, 1, 2).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В приведённом ниже решении первый раз всё срабатывает успешно:

```
$container.append($allElements.first());
```

Если дублировать эту строку и выполнить код, то перемещения до последовательности (3, 1, 2) уже не произойдёт. Возможно, я неправильно понял ранее изученное, но вроде как jQuery-объект меняет своё состояние, когда происходят какие-то изменения с соответствующими ему элементами DOM.

Пытаюсь снова сделать выборку вместо уже имеющегося объекта `$container`:

```
$('.container').append($allElements.first());
```

Тоже ничего не происходит. Объясните, пожалуйста, причины этого.

P. S. Можно решить поставленную задачу через замысловатые условия и арифметические операции, но стремясь к простоте кода, хотелось бы работать только в первым элементом `$allElements.first()` (в каждой итерации).

```js
let $container = $('.container');
let $allElements = $('.element');

$container.append($allElements.first());
//$container.append($allElements.first()); // не работает
//$('.container').append($allElements.first()); // так тоже
```

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.25);
  line-height: 1;
}

.element {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.element-first {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.25);
}
.element-second {
  background: rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.25);
}
.element-third {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.25);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="element element-first">1</div>
  <div class="element element-second">2</div>
  <div class="element element-third">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: это не вариант ? http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#cursor-style

Comment: @Максим Ленский, `jQueryUI-draggable` даёт возможность перетаскивать элементы курсором мыши. Может быть мне это и пригодилось, если бы я не делал слайдер. Так что в моём случае нужна полная автоматизация.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Коллекция в jQuery - это **НЕ** живая коллекция, поэтому, пока руками ее не модифицируешь, в ней ничего не поменяется.

Поэтому в твоем коде ты постоянно добавляешь один и тот же элемент.

В качестве решения в лоб, можно просто заново получать все элементы, хотя на самом деле, тебе нужен только первый.

Например так:

```js
let $container = $('.container');

$container.append($('.element:first-child'));
$container.append($('.element:first-child'));
```

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.25);
  line-height: 1;
}

.element {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.element-first {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.25);
}

.element-second {
  background: rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.25);
}

.element-third {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.25);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="element element-first">1</div>
  <div class="element element-second">2</div>
  <div class="element element-third">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ!

Answer (score 3):

Эта запись

```
let $allElements = $('.element');
```

один раз взяла последовательность и всегда при вызове

```
$allElements.first()
```

возвращает ссылку на один и тот же, попробуй так

```
let $container = $('.container');
$container.append($('.element').first());
$container.append($('.element').first());
```

Comment: что уже было сказано ниже. зачем тоже самое писать?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2yo9rkze/

Comment: @Tsyklop пока писал ответ, сказали

Comment: Спасибо Вам за ответ!

Answer (score 2):

Нужно ещё раз сделать выборку. Ибо когда ты сделал выборку первый раз у тебя всё и записалось как в первый раз - тобишь изменений в переменной $allElements не произошло.

```js
let $container = $('.container');
let $allElements = $('.element');

$container.append($allElements.first());
$container.append($('.element').first()); // уже работает
//$('.container').append($allElements.first()); // так тоже
```

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.25);
  line-height: 1;
}

.element {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.element-first {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.25);
}
.element-second {
  background: rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.25);
}
.element-third {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.25);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="element element-first">1</div>
  <div class="element element-second">2</div>
  <div class="element element-third">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: добавь пояснения в ответ, почему так должно сработать

Comment: @Grundy 

`$container.append($('.element').first());`
Нужно ещё раз сделать выборку. Ибо когда ты сделал выборку первый раз у тебя всё и записалось как в первый раз - тобишь изменений в переменной `$allElements` не произошло.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ!